# Change JSON value with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code. However, the problem with it is that it does not change `nameElem.data('index')`, so whenever the code runs it only shows element 1 in the list. How can I change the `nameElem.data('index')` json value? I tried `cardInfo[i].data.index = index;`, but that did not work.

```
$('#next').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nameElem = $('#team-name');
    var entries = nameElem.data('entries');
    var index = (nameElem.data('index') + 1) % entries.length;
    nameElem.text(entries[index]);
})
```

Keeping it simple: **How do I set a json value - nameElem.data('index') to var index?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a JSON value, I don't know why you're talking about JSON values... But anyways:

```
nameElem.data("index",index);
```

That should do it.

Comment: That did it - what is it then, if it's not a JSON value - sorry I thought it was one - today was actually my first time dealing with JSONification so I just assumed this was it. Anyways - what type of value is it, @Kolink ?

Comment: It's a `data` attribute. JSON is a string that represents an object, such as `"{foo:'bar'}"`